# Optimizing a recursive path finding algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, path-finding

On input i get width and height of matrix, string of text and another string of finalText I want to reach.
The characters of the first string are assigned to matrix.
My goal is to find shortest way to create finalText from characters in matrix, starting at position (0,0), and return number of steps.

So I create a dictionary of all coordinates and characters from finalText.

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, char> coords = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, char>();
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < width; j++){
   if (finalText.Contains(matrix[j, i]))
    coords.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(j, i), matrix[j, i]);
  }
}
```

And then use it in my function.
I basically calculate steps in all possible paths and then return the shortest one.

```
static int ShortestPath(char[,] matrix, string str, int x, int y, int steps, Dictionary<Tuple<int,int>,char> coords)
{
    if (str.Length == 0)
    {
        return steps;
    }

    else
    {
        List<int> l = new List<int>();

        foreach (var item in coords)
        {
            if (item.Value == str[0])
                l.Add(ShortestPath(matrix, str.Substring(1), item.Key.Item1, item.Key.Item2,
                    steps + (Math.Abs(x - item.Key.Item1) + Math.Abs(y - item.Key.Item2)), coords));
        }
                
        int min = l[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < l.Count; i++)
        {
            if (l[i] < min)
                min = l[i];
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

The algorithm is working, but for bigger matrices it's too slow and I have no idea how to optimize it or do it otherwise.

Comment: *The algorithm is working,* - codereview.stackexchange may be more appropriate

Comment: If you fail to reach your performance goal using C#, you can consider doing the number crunching  in C++. You can use C++/CLI to bridge between C# and C++. It's a common approach when implementing demanding algorithms.

Comment: I think this could profit from some memoization.

Comment: What you do here does not seem like an efficient approach. You are building a dictionary of coordinates that correspond to your match string, but you're not _using_ that dictionary as such - rather you just iterate over it as a list, looking for matching characters. --- Instead what I think you should be doing is the opposite: Build a dictionary keyed on the characters with a list of corresponding coordinates. That way you can look up just the matching coordinates for each character as you move over the string.

Comment: You mean like this:
`Dictionary<char, List<Tuple<int, int>>> coords = new Dictionary<char, List<Tuple<int, int>>>();`
And then iterate:
`foreach (var item in coords)
{
 if (item.Key == str[0])
 foreach (var value in item.Value)
 l.Add(ShortestPath(str.Substring(1), value.Item1, value.Item2, 
 steps + (Math.Abs(x - value.Item1) + Math.Abs(y - value.Item2)), coords));
}`

Comment: Yes, something like that (it's a bit hard to parse out of a comment).

Comment: (Cross-posted to [CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/275900/93149).)